# How to dismount a horse?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

I am in the tutorial level. I just mounted a horse and finished some tasks, yet now I am kind of stuck on the horse and do not know how to dismount. I also did not find any hint in the control setup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the horse is stopped you need to look down on the ground for the "Dismount" option to appear.

[image: Screenshot of the angle]